# A question about dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have this question and I don't know how to proceed:

> Suppose that $(f_n)$ is a sequence of measurable functions on $[0,1]$ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 |f_n|\, =0$ 
>   and that there is an integrable function $g$ on [0,1] such that $|f_n|^2\leq g$ for all $n$. Show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 |f_n|^2\, =0$.

I think that I must show $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 |f_n|\, = \displaystyle  \int_0^1 \lim_{n \to \infty}|f_n|$ , in other words I must show that we can take limit inside the integral.  What does $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 |f_n|\, =0$ mean? Can you help me for this question? Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear that $\lim_{n\to \infty} |f_n|$ exists in general.

Comment: I guess we will assume it because I wrote the whole question and there is nothing else.

Comment: No! Assuming that makes a huge difference in how easily it can be solved. It makes things way more trivial. Are you sure you want to assume that?

Comment: Oh I understand

Comment: Because if you assume $f_n$ converges  then you get by Fatou's Lemma that $\lim_{n\to\infty} |f_n|=0$ a.e. Then apply DCT: tada! All trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easier to argue by contradiction. Assume the contrary that

$$\int_0^1 |f_n|^2 dx$$

does not converge to $0$. Then by picking a subsequence if necessary, assume that there is $\epsilon_0>0$ so that

$$\tag{1} \int_0^1 |f_n|^2 dx \ge \epsilon_0.$$

The fact that $\int_0^1 |f_n| dx \to 0$ implies that (by picking a subsequence if necessary) $f_n \to 0$ almost everywhere. Thus $|f_n|^2 \to 0$ almost everywhere. Now one can use the condition $|f_n|^2 \le g$ and Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem to conclude

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 |f_n|^2 dx = \int_0^1 \lim_{n\to \infty} 0 dx = 0.$$

But this contradicts (1).

Comment: Well, this only proves a subsequence of $f_n$ converges to $0$ in $L^2$ instead of the whole sequence, I guess?

Comment: We argue by contradiction @CaveJohnson

Comment: Oh I get it. What a clever argument :-)

Comment: It seems to me that the first part up to (1) is unused in the rest of the proof, and could be deleted (turning this into a direct proof rather than one by contradiction). Am I correct?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni it uses the  fact that subsequences with the given properties exist. To make it direct you must show it for all subsequences which is not true in general. For example a subsequence that converges to zero a.e.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\int |f_n|=0$, we have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(|f_n|>1)=0$. By the absolute continuity of Lebesgue integral, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{|f_n|>1} g=0$. Henceforth
\begin{align}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int|f_n|^2&\le\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int_{|f_n|\le1}|f_n|^2+\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int_{|f_n|>1}|f_n|^2\\
&\le\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int_{|f_n|\le1}|f_n|+\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int_{|f_n|>1}g\\
&=0
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Start with a fact:

Let $(a_n)$ is a real sequence. $(a_n) \to L$ for some $L \in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if any subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ of $(a_n)$ has a further subsequence $(a_{n_{k_l}}) \to L$

Now take any subsequence $\displaystyle \int_0^1 |f_{n_k}|\to 0$. There exists a further subsequence  $f_{n_{k_l}}\to 0$ almost everywhere. Then as given in the question,  $|f_{n_{k_l}}|^2\leq g$ and $|f_{n_{k_l}}|^2 \to 0$. So by Dominated Convergence Theorem,

$\displaystyle \int_0^1|f_{n_{k_l}}|^2\to0$. And finally, by the fact above, $\displaystyle \int_0^1|f_n|^2\to0$.